# Prove that the knots 4_1 and 5_2 are not equivalent by showing one is p-colorable and the other is not for some prime p.

Tags: knot-theory

I've been learning about knot theory and I am a little confused how to prove the above statement. I know that the 4_1 knot (or the figure-eight knot) is not 3-colorable. However, it is 5-colorable. So when it says to prove it's p-colorable for some prime p, would it be considered p-colorable because it is 5-colorable? How would you prove this type of proposition?

Comment: There is no such thing as "p-colorable", but rather there is $p$-colorable for various values of $p$. The distinction is admittedly hard to see, but that font change is because $p$ is a variable, which simply means it is standing in for some unspecified number. So they are not talking about "p-colorable", but instead about "$2$-colorble, or $3$-colorable, or $5$-colorable, or $7$-colorable, or ....", I.e., they want you to find a particular value for $p$ (such as $p = 5$) for which one knot is colorable, and the other is not.

Answer (score 1):

Find a prime $p$ such that one of them is $p$-colorable and the other one not. In other words: For both knots, $p$ shall be the same.